# Get payload from String

Tags: javascript

I have this String:

`['TEST1-560', '{"data":[{"price":0.0815,"volume":0.2,"car":"BLUE"}],"isMasterFrame":false}']`

I want to get the keys 'TEST1-560' which is always fist and "car" value.

Do you know how I can implement this?

Comment: Sadly, the string is not JSON, so you cannot use `JSON.parse`.

Comment: Is there some other way?

Comment: Does your string always have the exact same structure? What differences could be there?

Comment: Yes, the structure is always the same.

Comment: so it's a string array. just select 1st item to get `TEST1-560`. Then you can parse into json 2nd element and from json you can get `car` value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very, very scuffed code, but it should work for your purpose if you have a string and you want to go through it. This can definitely be shortened and optimized, but assuming you have the same structure it will be fine.:

```
// Your data
var z = `['TEST1-560', '{"data":[{"price":0.0815,"volume":0.2,"car":"BLUE"}],"isMasterFrame":false}']`;
var testName = z.substring(2).split("'")[0];
var dividedVar = z.split(",");
for (var ind in dividedVar) {
  if (dividedVar[ind].split(":")[0] === '"car"') {
    var car = dividedVar[ind].split(":")[1].split("}")[0].substring(1,dividedVar[ind].split(":")[1].split("}")[0].length-1);
    console.log(car)
  }
}
console.log(testName);
```

output:

```
BLUE
TEST1-560
```

In a real application, you don't need to log the results, you can simply use the variables `testName`,`car`. You can also put this in a function if you want to handle many data, e.g.:

```
function parseData(z) {
    var testName = z.substring(2).split("'")[0];
    var dividedVar = z.split(",");
    for (var ind in dividedVar) {
        if (dividedVar[ind].split(":")[0] === '"car"') {
            var car = dividedVar[ind].split(":")[1].split("}")[0].substring(1, dividedVar[ind].split(":")[1].split("}")[0].length - 1);
        }
    }
    return [testName, car]
}
```

This will return the variables values in an array you can use

Answer (score 1):

```js
const arr = ['TEST1-560', '{"data":[{"price":0.0815,"volume":0.2,"car":"BLUE"}],"isMasterFrame":false}']

const testValue = arr[0];
const carValue = JSON.parse(arr[1]).data[0].car;

console.log(testValue);

console.log('-----------');
console.log(carValue);
```

If your structure is always the same, your data can be extracted like above.

Comment: This only works if you can supply the data as an array, but from my understanding, the data is supplied as a string

Comment: @ZaidAlShattle then need to wait for clarification from OP

Comment: "I have this String: ...", At least I think it was clear from that